# Действительно ли страницы сайта с ограниченным доступом не могут индексироваться поисковиками?

Tags: поисковые-системы

Ответ на этот вопрос логически понятен, но я, что называется, "перестраховываюсь на всякий случай". Итак, если я ограничиваю доступ к определённым страницам сайта аутентификацией (например, админ-панель), то верно ли, что поисковики не смогут просканировать эти страницы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Верно, поисковик видит только общедоступные страницы.

Видимость [можно проверить с помощью гугл](http://promored.ru/2012/12/google-translate-ne-po-naznacheniyu/) переводчика.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ!